# using Faker to fake images always returns false

Tags: php, linux, laravel, image, faker

Hello guys I'm trying to use Faker to populate images on my localhost but it always return false. this is my code

```
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
$faker = new Faker;
$faker::create()->image('public/images', 400, 300, null, false); // This returns false instead of the created image name.
```

I tried is with tinker and hardcoded in my code and always returns the same thing. I think it's because of permissions or something like that. I'm using kali linux. I also tried sudo chmod -R 777 on my folders but same problem still exists. Can anyone here help me?

Comment: Null or false? Can you post a dd of the result? Note that faker image uses curl requests, you should be able to execute curl calls otherwise it will bail and return false. Also, the 4th param should be a category name. Try for example 'people'. Instead of null.

Comment: This is how it works https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/blob/master/src/Faker/Provider/Image.php

Comment: using dd returns false too. nothing else just false. not null. JUST FALSE

Comment: I tried to visit https://lorempixel.com/ on my browser but it doesn't work. maybe this is the problem? I found this linx in the github link your put

Comment: OMG. I changed http://lorempixel.com with https://placekitten.com/ and it still returns false !

Comment: Check the code of faker image method, there is only one reason for returning false

Comment: If there's a connection error i believe it throws an exception so i don't think that's the problem

Comment: Thanks man I solved it. There was two errors. the first one was that lorempixel.com doesn't work with me (I don't know why I jsut try to visit it with my browser and it doesn't open. returns "This site can’t be reached").
So I replaced that link with placekitten.com and it returned the same problem "return false". after many attempts with curl to find out the problem I found that I must not use https with placekitten.com. I edited it and it works well! now should I close this discussion or edit the title or what. because I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Great man! Well done. Feel free to post an answer to reveal the root cause and solution.keep the question as a question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. There was two errors. the first one was that lorempixel.com doesn't work with me (I don't know why I just try to visit it with my browser and it doesn't open. returns "This site can’t be reached"). So I replaced that link with placekitten.com and it returned the same problem "return false". after many attempts with curl to find out the problem I found that I must not use https with placekitten.com. I edited it and it works well!

Comment: Great, please post the final code you used that works so others can benefit and learn from it.

Comment: All Changes I did was on this file "/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Provider/Image.php" And this is the file after my edits. I uploaded it to pastebin
https://pastebin.com/MU6m2EMc

Comment: Ok, that's a diagnose workaround, but note that its not supposed to edit files under the vendor directory, as you will lose chamges upon next package upgrade. You may check your network against lorempixel and/or open an issue to fzaninotto and ask how can you switch the image service at user level.

Comment: Thanks mate I appreciate your help